# Cheapest way to reach Peru from India

Tags: india, peru, ships

I want to go to Peru next year. Air fare is mighty expensive, then it struck me, it might be possible to go by ship. And it would be fun, I'd actually see ocean journey and see the geography which I would be crossing to reach Peru. Also there might be port stops which way I would get to see more of the world. It might even be possible that I can secure a job on a ship on its way to Peru, that way I might even make money out of the travel. So how do I do it?

Comment: It's a difficult flight to make. Fun fact: Lima and Bengaluru are both 12°N latitude  and 77° longitude. The problem is that one is 77°East and the other one is 77° West :-). It's a long trip. Nothing from Lima flies to the west. The western most city you can get from Lima is Los Angeles which unfortunately has no flights to India. So you need to take the long way round: either over the pole or through Europe.

Comment: @Hilmar the latitude as well is in different hemispheres.

Comment: @Hilmar:  The [great-circle route between Lima and India](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LIM-AMS-DEL,+LIM-DEL) goes east anyhow.  From 77°W to 77°E is a span of 154° going east and a span of 206° going west.  Going through Europe only adds about 70 miles to the total flight distance.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert not if you're going directly to Bengaluru, in which case going through Amsterdam [adds about 550 miles](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=LIM-AMS-BLR,+LIM-BLR).

Comment: @phoog:  Fair enough, but the great circle route still goes east, not west.  :-)

Comment: "Ocean journey", "see geography". Honestly, I wouldn't think that there's that much to see once you're far enough from the coast (~5 miles) to no longer see land. It's going to be pretty much the same blue/green/grey ocean view for days on end....

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Traveling by cargo ship is possible, but will not be cheaper than flying, and requires flexibility in time and destination on your end. You can search your way through this, but [this page](https://www.flightlesstravel.com/plan/cargo-ships/) lists a few options for booking. As it stands, the going rate for passage on cargo ships is 100 to 125 USD per day, and you can forget about lowering the cost by doing chores.

On the other hand, you *could* become a sailor, but that's an other story.

A quick search for flights shows a minimum cost of about 1500 euros for a round trip from Delhi to Lima. If you spend time on finding just the right dates and connections, you would be able to lower this by a few hundred euros, to around 1000. At the moment, there's [this connection](https://skiplagged.com/flights/delhi/LIM/2024-02-12/2024-02-26#trip=BA142-AA57-AA1307,AA918-AA1199-AA292) at under 900 GBP. It won't get much cheaper than that.

Comment: Can you please convert (or do an estimation) in one currency? Some of us are familiar enough with US dollar, British pound and euro to understand, I do not expect someone from India to be that experienced.

Comment: Thank you, I converted that all to INR. Wow, I would never have imagined flight would be cheapest by far. I can't believe cargo ships cost as much as 125 dollars A DAY? Considering a around 40 day journey to Peru, that's one way to empty the bank before even reaching Peru.

Comment: @JohnSnow imagine a 40-day journey on foot, so without transportation cost.  You will need 120 meals and 39 hotel rooms.  Even at $15 a night for accommodation and $5 a meal, which is an order of magnitude too small for much of the world, you're looking at $1185.

Comment: @JohnSnow $125/day includes all meals and accommodation. I too have been wanting to travel by cargo ship, but it's certainly not a way to save money. From what I've read, finding short-term jobs on ships has become very difficult these days. In some cases, sailors working on ships may not even be allowed to leave the ship, or if they are, only in a very limited area of the harbour.

Comment: @JohnSnow: "I would never have imagined flight would be cheapest by far." It's been a sad truth for many years now. E.g. in Europe, trains are typically 3 or 5 times more expensive than the corresponding flights.

Comment: @JohnSnow It starts making more sense if you think as planes as the, by far, quickest way for a company to transport people thousands of kilometres. Consider that an airliner spends a few hours transporting you, but a freighter over a month ... time is money, as they say.

Comment: @xLeitix: It still doesn't make sense at all if you consider the required energy or the environmental impact, though.

Comment: @EricDuminil It's not the environment that prices goods and services, sadly.

Comment: @EricDuminil planes are cheaper than sea travel because instead of a cabin several meters on a side all they need to give you is a seat that takes up less than 1 square meter.  I don't know the economics of rail, but If I had to guess why its so much more expensive, it'd be the cost of all the land the tracks themselves are built on.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight: From https://www.context.news/net-zero/why-is-travelling-by-train-so-much-more-expensive-than-flying : `The research said many countries charge railways value-added taxes (VAT), energy taxes and high tolls while exempting plane tickets from VAT and not taxing kerosene fuel.`

Comment: @EricDuminil Comparing against a 13 euro London to Barcelona flunks the smell test to the extent that I find myself skeptical of everything else in the articles claims because that has to be well below the airlines cost.  Meaning it's either missing a huge number of taxes and fees, is a bait promotion comprising a negligible share of the airlines actual seats on the route or some other stunt.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight: Compare the average or median prices, then. Flights would still be much cheaper than trains, and the taxes reasons are still valid. 13€ flight London -> Barcelona might not be common or representative, but extremely cheap flights do happen. You probably won't find any corresponding train travel for less than 250€.

Comment: In India domestic flight is still ( only marginally though) more expensive than a first class rail ticket, but I guess that's because the domestic airline fleet strength is still below demand.

Comment: @EricDuminil, you start to find London to the continent train tickets for around 30 pound, through France tickets for 25 Euro, not sure about the Paris to Barcelona tickets but if booked 3 to 4 months in advance on non-flex tickets trains travel can be under €100 for that kind of distance.  High speed train and long distance overnight train do change the picture.

Answer (score 3):

I visited Peru in 2018 from India. The route I took was New Delhi -> Moscow -> New York -> Miami -> Quito, Ecuador. I took Aeroflot from New Delhi to Moscow. I took Jet Blue from Miami to Quito.

Then I went to Peru by crossing the Ecuador-Peru border by a boat on a tributary of the amazon river at Nuevo Rocafuerte. This was because Ecuador was in my itinerary too. At that time, this was the cheapest route I had found.

There are plenty of flights from Miami to Lima if you want to go to Peru directly by skipping Ecuador.

Expanding this answer upon OPs request though it doesn't directly relate to the question:

1. Yes, you would have to apply for the Visa for each country. If you have a visiting Visa for US, then you get a Peruvian Visa at the border. Ecuador was visa-free entry when I traveled but they have changed their conditions and now a visa is needed to enter Ecuador. You probably have to get it before hand.
2. I don't remember the exact cost but it cost me around Rs.13,00,000 (INR) for 6 months of backpacking through Ecuador -> Peru -> Chile -> Bolivia -> Peru. Then back to India via US and Japan.

I would highly recommend Bolivia as its cheap. But be careful with the Visa. Legally, it's (was?) visa free entry. But the border crossing official between San Pedro and Uyuni refused to let me in until I paid him around 100USD. Perhaps, my not so sober face made me an easy victim. So better get a Visa before hand.

Comment: Hey I'd love to do that. Can you please expand your answer? How does one hop through several countries? Does one need to apply for each country visa? Please give the numbers too, what did it cost you each step?